# given a binary tree where each node has some weight. You have to return the max weight in the binary tree

Tags: java, c, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Q>  given a binary tree where each node has some weight. You have to return the max weight in the binary tree.

Maxweight = value of root node + value in its left subtree and right subtree.

Ex  - 2
   /   \
  -1    3
Output = 4

Comment: How can you learn if you don't do your own homework?

Answer (score 2):

It can be easily solved with recursion, until there are no child nodes left. Here is a quick example:

```
weight = getWeight(rootNode)

getWeight(node)
{
   if node != null
       return node.weight + getWeight(node.leftChild) + getWeight(node.rightChild)
   else
      return 0
}
```